# Splitting Full name into First Middle Last and Suffix SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to parse a full name to read as First name, Middle name, Last name and Suffix.
I have half a SQL code I've attempted, but I  need assistance getting the Suffix based off of the following logic.

If there is no Suffix, leave field NULL
If there is no Middle Name, leave field NULL

,Ltrim(SubString(NAME, 1, Isnull(Nullif(CHARINDEX(' ', NAME), 0), 1000))) AS FirstName
,Ltrim(SUBSTRING(NAME, CharIndex(' ', NAME), CASE
WHEN (CHARINDEX(' ', NAME, CHARINDEX(' ', NAME) + 1) - CHARINDEX(' ', NAME)) <= 0
THEN 0
ELSE CHARINDEX(' ', NAME, CHARINDEX(' ', NAME) + 1) - CHARINDEX(' ', NAME)
END)) AS MiddleName

```
,Ltrim(SUBSTRING(NAME, 
Isnull(Nullif(CHARINDEX(' ', NAME, Charindex(' ', NAME) + 1), 0), CHARINDEX(' ', NAME)), CASE 
            WHEN Charindex(' ', NAME) = 0
                THEN 0
            ELSE LEN(NAME)
            END)) AS LastName
```

```
Thanks in advance


Example: 

an example of the full name is Alexander BC Brendel Jr , The desired outcome would be First - Alexander Middle - BC Last - Brendel Suffix - Jr 


|HdrName                |FirstName |MiddleName  |LastName   |Suffix|
|--------               |--------- |----------- |---------- |------|
|Alexander BC Brendel Jr|Alexander |BC          |Brendel    |Jr    |
|Thomas J Abraham  Sr   |Thomas    |J           |Abraham    |Sr    |
```

Comment: [edit] any improvements directly into your question, and ensure your sample data also considers all edge cases.

Comment: provide sample data & desired output

Comment: Required reading: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). TL;DR: you don't. Any assumptions you make will be wrong.

Comment: The data is stored the way it is needed. and I got half of the results I needed, not really sure what this reading will do.

Comment: The reading will show you that not all names will follow that format. Some will have no suffix, some will have no middle initial/name. Its very very hard to to anything sensible with a random string that represents a name.

Comment: "The data is stored the way it is needed" But you can't assume that the name is space delimited.  Mary Ann Smith 's middle name is not necessarily Ann.  Plus some cultures put the names in a different order.

Comment: *"not really sure what this reading will do."* Exactly what I said; all your assumptions are wrong. If you change your assumptions, they are wrong. If you try to improve your assumptions, they are wrong, and when you finally work out all those assumptions are wrong, and create a new assumption, it is wrong

Comment: Hum: my first name is Lord, my middle is Smith and my surname is Junior, are you going to parse that correctly?

Answer (score 1):

If the format of **HdrName** column is constant and consist exactly of four parts,
then you are lucky — there is a special function in SQL Server exactly for your case:

```
DECLARE @Names TABLE (HdrName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @Names VALUES ('Alexander BC Brendel Jr'), ('Thomas J Abraham Sr');

WITH PreparedNames AS 
(
    SELECT 
        HdrName,
        FullName = REPLACE(HdrName, ' ', '.')
    FROM
        @Names
)
SELECT
    HdrName     ,
    Suffix      =   PARSENAME(FullName, 1),
    FirstName   =   PARSENAME(FullName, 4),
    MiddleName  =   PARSENAME(FullName, 3),
    LastName    =   PARSENAME(FullName, 2)
FROM
    PreparedNames;
```

[PARSENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function is used to parse the four-part names of SQL Server objects, however if to replace the spaces in your names with dots, your names can be parsed as SQL Server objects.

Comment: Very risky.   If (for example) there is no suffix:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=6a64e7dea1b47e1f0b7005dad559c7b4

Answer (score 0):

I used the function [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K] from here:

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%e2%80%9ccsv-splitter%e2%80%9d-function

Then I created my own function to determine which parts of a name should be labeled and returned. It may be a terrible way to do it, but the system I manage heavily relies on the names being parsed properly from a mainframe and this is the best I could come up with.

```
/**************************************************************************************************
Name:        GetMultiNamePart
Author:      Tommy Harris
Date:        February 13, 2023
Dependences: None            
Description: Name parser that breaks out the parts of a name into Title, First, Middle, Last and Suffix.
Parameters:
            @FullName - Name to be split
            @Part - First, Middle, Last, Suffix, Title
            @Order - Order of the name to parse. (LFMS,LSFM,FMLS)
                1. LFMS: Last, First, Middle, Suffix
                2. LSMS: Last, Suffix, First, Middle
                3. FMLS: First, Middle, Last, Suffix
*****************************************************************************************************/
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetMultiNamePart]
(
    @FullName   varchar(8000) = '',
    @Part       varchar(15) = '',
    @Order      varchar(5) = 'LFMS'
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(120)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NameToReturn   VARCHAR(120) = ''
    DECLARE @NamePartCount  INT

    /******************************************************************
    /Declare the Name Parts table where the individual parts will be stored.
    ******************************************************************/
    DECLARE @NameParts TABLE
    (
        ItemNumber  INT,
        Item        VARCHAR(8000),
        ItemType    VARCHAR(50)
    )

    /******************************************************************
    /Insert the split out name parts
    ******************************************************************/
    INSERT INTO @NameParts
    (
        ItemNumber,     Item,       ItemType
    )
    SELECT 
        ItemNumber,     Item,       ''
    FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(replace(replace(@FullName, ' ', ','), '  ',' '), ',') p

    /******************************************************************
    / Find the entries relating to Titles, update the Item Type.
    ******************************************************************/
    UPDATE @NameParts
    SET ItemType = 'Title'
    WHERE Item IN ('Dr','Dr.','Mr','Mr.','Mrs','Mrs.','Hon','Hon.','Miss','Miss.','Sir','Sir.')

    /******************************************************************
    / Find the entries relating to Suffix, update the Item Type.
    ******************************************************************/
    UPDATE @NameParts
    SET ItemType = 'Suffix'
    WHERE Item IN ('Jr.','Jr','Sr.','Sr','Esq','Esq.','I','II','III','IV','I.','II.','III.','IV.','V','VI','V.','VI.')

    /******************************************************************
    / Delete any entries that are blank. This could be erroneous entries
    / because there are 2 spaces between name parts.
    ******************************************************************/
    DELETE FROM @NameParts
    WHERE RTRIM(Item) = ''

    /******************************************************************
    / Get the count of the number of parts of the name, minus the suffix.
    ******************************************************************/
    SET @NamePartCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @NameParts WHERE ItemType = '')

    /******************************************************************
    / Check the number of parts of the name to determine how to parse them.
    / TO DO: check formats again with more test data.
    ******************************************************************/
    IF @NamePartCount > 2
    BEGIN
        /******************************************************************
        / Check the format of the name to determine the order that the first
        / and last names get assigned. Assign the remaining name parts in the 
        / middle as middle names.
        ******************************************************************/
        IF @Order IN ('LSFM','LFMS')
        BEGIN
            With ln As
            (
                SELECT TOP 1 ItemNumber,ItemType
                FROM @NameParts
                WHERE ItemType = ''
                ORDER BY ItemNumber ASC
            )
            UPDATE ln SET ItemType = 'Last'
            WHERE ItemNumber = ln.ItemNumber; --DIBE

            With fn As
            (
                SELECT TOP 1 ItemNumber,ItemType
                FROM @NameParts
                WHERE ItemType = ''
                ORDER BY ItemNumber ASC
            )
            UPDATE fn SET ItemType = 'First'
            WHERE ItemNumber = fn.ItemNumber;

            UPDATE @NameParts 
            SET ItemType = 'Middle'
            WHERE ItemType = ''
        END
        ELSE IF @Order = 'FMLS'
        BEGIN
            With fn As
            (
                SELECT TOP 1 ItemNumber,ItemType
                FROM @NameParts
                WHERE ItemType = ''
                ORDER BY ItemNumber ASC
            )
            UPDATE fn SET ItemType = 'First'
            WHERE ItemNumber = fn.ItemNumber;

            With ln As
            (
                SELECT TOP 1 ItemNumber,ItemType
                FROM @NameParts
                WHERE ItemType = ''
                ORDER BY ItemNumber DESC
            )
            UPDATE ln SET ItemType = 'Last'
            WHERE ItemNumber = ln.ItemNumber;

            UPDATE @NameParts 
            SET ItemType = 'Middle'
            WHERE ItemType = ''
        END
    END
    ELSE IF @NamePartCount = 2
    BEGIN
        /******************************************************************
        / Check the format of the name to determine the order that the first
        / and last names get assigned. Middle names do not exist in this.
        ******************************************************************/
        IF @Order IN ('LSFM','LFMS')
        BEGIN
            With ln As
            (
                SELECT TOP 1 ItemNumber,ItemType
                FROM @NameParts
                WHERE ItemType = ''
                ORDER BY ItemNumber ASC
            )
            UPDATE ln SET ItemType = 'Last'
            WHERE ItemNumber = ln.ItemNumber;

            With fn As
            (
                SELECT TOP 1 ItemNumber,ItemType
                FROM @NameParts
                WHERE ItemType = ''
                ORDER BY ItemNumber ASC
            )
            UPDATE fn SET ItemType = 'First'
            WHERE ItemNumber = fn.ItemNumber;
        END
        ELSE IF @Order = 'FMLS'
        BEGIN
            With fn As
            (
                SELECT TOP 1 ItemNumber,ItemType
                FROM @NameParts
                WHERE ItemType = ''
                ORDER BY ItemNumber ASC
            )
            UPDATE fn SET ItemType = 'First'
            WHERE ItemNumber = fn.ItemNumber;

            With ln As
            (
                SELECT TOP 1 ItemNumber,ItemType
                FROM @NameParts
                WHERE ItemType = ''
                ORDER BY ItemNumber DESC
            )
            UPDATE ln SET ItemType = 'Last'
            WHERE ItemNumber = ln.ItemNumber;
        END
    END
    ELSE IF @NamePartCount = 1
    BEGIN
        /******************************************************************
        / If only one unassigned ItemType exists, assume its the first name.
        ******************************************************************/
        With fn As
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 ItemNumber,ItemType
            FROM @NameParts
            WHERE ItemType = ''
            ORDER BY ItemNumber DESC
        )
        UPDATE fn SET ItemType = 'First'
        WHERE ItemNumber = fn.ItemNumber;       
    END

    /******************************************************************
    / Return the part of the name as the output value based on the part requested
    ******************************************************************/
    IF @Part = 'Middle' 
    BEGIN
        /******************************************************************
        / Concatenate the middle name fields.
        ******************************************************************/
        SET @NameToReturn = ISNULL((SELECT STUFF( (SELECT ' ' + Item 
                             FROM @NameParts 
                             WHERE ItemType = 'Middle'
                             ORDER BY ItemNumber
                             FOR XML PATH('')), 
                            1, 1, '')),'')
    END
    ELSE IF @Part = 'Full' 
    BEGIN
        SET @NameToReturn = ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 Item FROM @NameParts WHERE ItemType = 'First') + ' ','')
        SET @NameToReturn = @NameToReturn + ISNULL((SELECT STUFF( (SELECT ' ' + Item 
                             FROM @NameParts 
                             WHERE ItemType = 'Middle'
                             ORDER BY ItemNumber
                             FOR XML PATH('')), 
                            1, 1, '')) + ' ','')
        SET @NameToReturn = @NameToReturn + ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 Item FROM @NameParts WHERE ItemType = 'Last') + ' ','')
        SET @NameToReturn = @NameToReturn + ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 Item FROM @NameParts WHERE ItemType = 'Suffix'),'')
        SET @NameToReturn = RTRIM(@NameToReturn)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        /******************************************************************
        / Get just the part of the name requested.
        ******************************************************************/
        SET @NameToReturn = ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 Item FROM @NameParts WHERE ItemType = @Part),'')
    END

    RETURN @NameToReturn
END
```